# Сколько существует подотрезков с заданной суммой

Tags: c++, алгоритм, оптимизация

есть вопрос. Дан массив чисел a, где (-10^9 <= ai <= 10^9). Для этого массива чисел нужно найти подотрезок массива с максимальной суммой, вывезти эти сумму и количество таких подотрезков. С поиском максимальной суммы я справился (код прилагаю), а вот как быстро найти количество я не особо понимаю. Если у вас есть какие-либо идеи, буду очень благодарен.

```
 int n;
 cin >> n;
 vector<int> a(n);
 for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) cin >> a[i];

 int ans = a[0], sum = 0;
 for (int r = 0; r < n; ++r) {
      sum += a[r];
      ans = max(ans, sum);
      sum = max(sum, 0);
 }
 cout << ans;
```

```
unordered_map<int, int> check;
int s[n + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      s[i + 1] = s[i] + a[i];
       if (check.find(s[i + 1]) != check.end()) {
           ++check[s[i + 1]];
       } else {
          check[s[i + 1]] = 1;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посчитайте кумулятивные суммы ( суммы от первого до k-го элемента) и складывайте их в словарь.

Если в словаре есть ключ currentsum-best - вы нашли отрезок с суммой best. А если хранить в значении количество сумм, вы получите количество отрезков

Код на Python без использования языковых особенностей:

```
a = [1,1,-3,3,-2,-1,2,-2,2,1]
cs = 0
res = 0
best = 3
dic = {0:1}
for x in a:
    cs += x

    if cs-best in dic:
        res += dic[cs-best]

    if cs in dic:
        dic[cs] = dic[cs]+1
    else:
        dic[cs] = 1
    print(cs)
print(dic)
print(res)

1 2 -1 2 0 -1 1 -1 1 2
{1: 3, 2: 3, -1: 3, 0: 2}
4
```

Comment: Я немного не понимаю, как суммы на префиксе дадут суммы на случайном подотрезке

Comment: Разность двух префиксов - это сумма на отрезке

Comment: Теперь ясно, но что в словаре будет ключом, а что значением. Просто я не понимаю как разность двух префиксов положить в словарь

Comment: Ключ - префиксная сумма, значение - количество таких сумм, в первый раз в значение кладёте 1, потом обновляете

Comment: Я добавил код подсчёта, вы это имели ввиду?

Comment: Да, не полностью - вы правильно создаёте нужный словарь, только в начале положите в него пару 0:1, но пока не используете его для поиска результата. Я добавил Python код для справки. Суммы хранить не нужно.